# Firebase hosting deploy is not deployed to one of the free domains : my-project-id.web.app, not on my-project-id.firebsaseapp.com

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

As I know firebase allows our website to be deployed to free hosting services on two free domains. Which are:

1. my-project-id.firebaseapp.com,
2. my-project-id.web.app

I am trying to upload my static website to firebase hosting using cmd `firebase deploy`. But it is only uploaded to web.app, while not uploaded to firebaseapp.com.
Earlier some days it was working well.

Please help how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had faced something similar to this:

After a deploy, my site was not getting updated on `web.app` and when I used Chrome Dev tools, it turned out to be the old code. However, the code was updated on `firebaseapp.com`.

The actual reason is still unknown to me, but there are a high chance that this is some sort of cache issue. I was testing my site on 'web.app' like a lot of time, many refreshes and deploys..

I just Disabled Cache during testing thereafter.

[image]

I faced no such issue after that...

Try hard refresh or whatever it is called using `Ctrl + Shift + R` and `Ctrl + F5`

Answer (score 0):

This is unexpected as all Firebase Hosting applications should behave identically on `web.app` and `firebaseapp.com`. I'd recommend reaching out to Firebase Support for help.

Comment: FWIW, I am also seeing the same issue 1 year later in 2 different Firebase projects (including one brand new, bare minimum AngularFire project). It doesn't look like a client-side caching issue because I've tried several browsers on multiple devices, including force refresh like other answers have suggested. The `firebaseapp.com` website works fine while the `web.app` one shows the "Site not found" page. Are there any differences in how the 2 domains are handled internally?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when using Chrome.  I tried Edge and both URLs worked fine.  It's probably some setting in Chrome. I tried disabling cache but that didn't help.  Test with another browser.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to: [Firebase default hosting domains: only .firebaseapp.com works but .web.app fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67068481/firebase-default-hosting-domains-only-firebaseapp-com-works-but-web-app-fails/73994231#73994231)

TLDR; [Solved] Ctrl+F5 to force hard reset (to clear cache)