# Firebase default hosting domains: only .firebaseapp.com works but .web.app fails

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm building a very simple one-page react application using typescript. I tried hosting it using Firebase Hosting. Surprisingly, only the domain *[name].firebaseapp.com* works but *[name].web.app* shows the "Site not found" default page:

[site-not-found image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYZgd.png)

I am using a basic firebase config (the default one you get using `firebase init`):

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

I get the "Site not found" when I go on *[name].web.app*. I would have suspected something was wrong with the `index.html`, the rewrites, the build folder, etc... but then why would I see the page functional on *[name].firebaseapp.com* and hosted nicely and it should be?

There is a few things I suspect:

- The domain name is not available from firebase itself (although why would firebase name the domain something that is invalid if that was the case when creating the project)
- The files are being pushed to the *[name].firebaseapp.com* domain only (in that case, how can you control that?)

Comment: *firebaser here* That sounds unusual, as the two subdomains are mapped to the same resources. It's literally a single deploy with two DNS mappings. You might want to try running `firebase deploy` again just in case, but it that doesn't work, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for the confirmation that it's an unusual behavior. I totally agree with your comment about it being a single deploy and just two DNS mappings. Running ```firebase deploy``` again does not work. I will reach out to the support and update the thread with what they answer. Thanks!

Comment: I got this same issue, really weird... It worked the next day even without contacting support. May be some proxy-caching issue at firebase

Comment: Same here. https://thazhamburrising.firebaseapp.com/ works, https://thazhamburrising.web.app/ doesn't work. Waited for 12 hours. Let me wait for another 12 hours before contacting support.

Comment: Same issue here. I have a feeling it was because I opened the domain before anything was deployed and it cached the "Site Not Found" page. I'll wait 12 hours and see if it gets fixed.
https://johannes-nicholas.firebaseapp.com/ Works.
https://johannes-nicholas.web.app/ Does not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The same weird problem happened to me this weekend. Exact symptoms:

- before any deployments, I opened `example.web.app` but not `example.firebaseapp.com`
- after the first deployment, `example.web.app` shows "Site not found" but `example.firebaseapp.com` works as expected. Consequently my customer domain shows "Site not found" as well.

---

**Per one of the suggestions by support, now fixed by these commands:**

```
curl -X PURGE https://your.notworking.url
```

For my case, it was just `example.web.app` and my custom domain. So fixed in 20 seconds.

---

Suggestions that did **NOT** work:

- messing with the browser (clear browser cache, incognito mode etc)
- re-deploying

Explanation:

The site not found thing got cached on their CDN server. So naturally, clearing local browser cache did not work. Weirdly re-deploying also did not working.

Another helpful note is, in the response there is a `x-served-by` header, which tells you the CDN server your web app is cached on.

Special thanks to *Hugo Varela* from firebase support.

Comment: hi @mightbesimon. this solution makes sense, thanks for explaining. I will mark it as the "accepted" solution so others read it and do as you said above.

Answer (score 9):

**Update:**

I emailed customer support at firebase, and the next day the domain was working normally. No explanation was provided on why the issue occurred, but emailing them solved it.

Comment: This works and I don't know why. I am not sure if it is interfered by the support team. Maybe it is casused by some very slow process(like propagation). But my issue is solved within 12h or less.

Comment: Firebase Support is awful. I've had to contact support several times because I've waited weeks and they didn't respond back. Once they finally responded, they give the generic "clear the cache and test on Incognito window" which I already did, emailed them back, and they didn't even respond, so I had to contact support again! Awful customer support.

Answer (score 1):

This solved it for me:

Hard Refresh `CTRL + F5`
OR
Close browser (close all tabs) THEN reopen in a fresh instance.

This looks like a caching issue where the previous version of the code is cached.

Comment: hey, unfortunately in my case even retrying on a different device with a clean setup did not work. Must have been CDN caching as mentioned by @mightbesimon below