# Firebase site is not deploying at .web.app

Tags: firebase-hosting

I've deployed my site in firebase project. It deployed correctly but i can't see that at .web.app site. It shows only in .firebaseapp.com site but not in .web.app. I can view my site at .web.app/index.html. Please let me know the solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: That's unusual. If a redeploy doesn't fix it, I recommend you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67068481/firebase-default-hosting-domains-only-firebaseapp-com-works-but-web-app-fails

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase default hosting domains: only .firebaseapp.com works but .web.app fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67068481/firebase-default-hosting-domains-only-firebaseapp-com-works-but-web-app-fails)

Answer (score -1):

It could be a caching issue, have you tried another browser or cleared your browser cache with `Ctrl F5`

If the project is new, it may also be a DNS config issue on their end and simply needs time to update, typically 24 hours should suffice.